# Misalignment in design when I change the layout to different size in priview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-viewpager, android-view

I am developing a new Android application. I need to design the below screenshot in my application . I am using eclipse IDE.

[image]

Using the below code I formed the above shown screen-shot. But whenever I choose the different screen previews ( 4.7’’ WXGA ,  4.0” WXGA etc., )  am getting  the inner images which are marked with arrows in the below scree shot are misaligned. The below is the screen shot which is an example. All the images in the layout are icons ( Ex., home, share ).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bar"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:src="@drawable/rec_button_stop"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" android:layout_marginTop="90dip"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dip"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

    </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:src="@drawable/rec_button_stop" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />
    </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

So I need the samller images ( icons which are marked with arrows) to be fixed at the same position ( in straight line ) whenever I change the screen priviews with different sizes.

Can some one guide me with some code snippets or with some links.

Comment: Abandon LinearLayout.  Learn about RelativeLayout, Redo your XML (by the way, XML is not code, it's data) then come back if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@2Vision2 :  This problem is caused because you have used fixed margin in layout components.

For supporting various size devices you have to create different layouts. You are facing this problem because you are using only single layout. Create 4 directories in res/ directory in your app for layouts of all sizes

- layout  (for devices below 4")
- layout-800X480  (for devices above 4" & below 5")
- layout-sw620dp  (for 7" tablets)
- layout-sw800dp  (for 10" tablets)

Also if want to create different layouts for landscape mode then create layout-land, layout-land-800X480,.. directories for supporting app in landscape mode also.

Answer (score 1):

try this xml file,this will work universally in all sizes(land & port)!actually you may be using wrong way to use weight.
hope this will help you getting idea how to set layout and gravity,with the use of WEIGHT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:gravity="center|top" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

weight can be also used in Relative Layout.but preffered way to use it with linear Layout.

still any query, plz ask...