# Same XML - Different Layouts - API 10 and API 17

Tags: android, api, android-layout, android-xml

The xml bellow generates two distincts layouts screens depending on the API. This layout in a device with the API 17, the layout looks good, with the inputs texts centralized on the screen.

But the same layout running on the API 10 seems weird, with the fields in the up left corner...

xml code snippet as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#005500">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText 
          android:id="@+id/et_nome_login"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dip"
          android:paddingRight="15dip"
          android:paddingLeft="15dip"
          android:inputType="text"
          android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_senha_login"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_login_name"/>

        <EditText 
          android:id="@+id/et_senha_login"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dip"
          android:paddingRight="15dip"
          android:paddingLeft="15dip"
          android:inputType="textPassword"
          android:background="@drawable/bg_login_senha"/>

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/ib_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_entrar"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AA000000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

On the API 10 the views are placed at the up left corner, and on the API 17 the fields are corrected placed in the center. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can include different xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/include_file" />
```

Different xml must be in own API folders with same name:

Values-v11

- include_file.xml
- ...

Values-v14

- include_file.xml
- ...

Comment: thanks for your help, but this is not the case. Or I'm not understanding...
The layout must be the same....my question is why the sabe xml generates two different screens depending on the API... this layout only contains elements that do part of android since the old versions of the APIs.... I can't understanding this difference...

Answer (score 0):

you should use weight property to run one xml in every size or API.

try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455386/misalignment-in-design-when-i-change-the-layout-to-different-size-in-priview/17466792#17466792)

Comment: Rumit thanks for your reply.
I tried many combinations using weight but it didn't work. It has the same behavior....